# Nested function arguments with partials

Tags: clojure

I have this function definition, but I was wondering if it was possible to do this with just a def and higher order functions (i'd like the result to take args in the same order)

```
(defn f1
  [a b c]
  (f2
   (partial f3 a)
   b c))
```

f2 and f3 look like (keeping arguments relevantly named):

```
(defn f2
  [f b c]
  (my-fn-using f b c))

(defn f3
  [a x c]
  (another-fn-using a x c))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a 100% sure I understand what you are asking, but here's my take on an answer.

Converting `f1` to a HOF could involve modifying it to take the arguments `[f g a b c]` and calling it using `f` and `g` as `my-fn-using` and `another-fn-using`.

```
(defn f1 [f g a b c]
  (f (partial g a) b c))
```

You would then call it as:

```
(f1 my-fn-using another-fn-using a b c)
```

Which would be applied as:

```
(my-fn-using (partial another-fn-using a) b c)
```

The reason that I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for is that you mention "nested function arguments", but I don't see where those are. Missing arguments for `another-fn-using` come from inside `my-fn-using` when the former is called, and the latter gets its arguments directly.

For example:

```
(defn my-fn-using [f b c]
  (let [x [:b b]]
    ;; do stuff using b and/or c
    (f x c)))

(defn another-fn-using [a x c]
  ;; do other stuff using a x c
  [a x c])

;; call f1 
(f1 my-fn-using another-fn-using 1 2 3)

;; or create a partially applied function that takes [a b c]
(def f (partial f1 my-fn-using another-fn-using))

(f 1 2 3)
```